# How does Windows page when there are multiple pagefiles on multiple disks?

Tags: windows, pagefile, performance-tuning

Let's say I have two internal HDDs and configure Windows to place pagefiles on both of them. How do pagefile writes occur?

Are pagefile writes spread evenly across the disks?

Does Windows prefer accessing the higher-performing disk (perhaps measured through pagefile I/Os)?

Does Windows access them sequentially, starting on disk #1, and only proceeding to the pagefile on the second disk when the first is full?

Why I ask: If there are two disks with greatly different performance characteristics (a 5.4K HDD and 15K HDD, for example), it could potentially be a detriment to place a pagefile on both disks if the one on the higher-performing disk will never be accessed.

Comment: Various info at microsoft claims that it leans toward using the faster one. one on a seperate disk to the disk that programs are running from would be "faster" because there would be less simeltanious I/O occuring there. They also stated that it was not utalised in a "raid" style, where some of it would go one place and some to the other for speed. I use it so minimally, I just setup the speedy disk and dropped the rest.  Because you can see Pagefile accesses in resource monitor and the location, you could know, on your system.

Comment: I just tested it again, little paging on C: and big one on F: , to force some paging, get the program RamMap, which will shove the "working sets" out of ram, forcing paging.  It used both. That is probably why I set it to just the one, keep it simple.

Comment: The answer is moot if you want Windows to be able to create Crash Dumps on BSOD. If so, the page file on your boot drive needs to be at least a minimum size. Setting it lower than this disables the creation of Crash Dumps (it warns you when you try). I usually set the recommended size or Auto on the fastest drive, and minimum to leave Crash Dumps on the boot drive.